# Cookie is not loading to browser

Tags: django, vue.js, cookies, django-rest-framework

I have this LoginView in django rest framework.

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, ]

    def post(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Response({'message': 'User is already logged in'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            email = serializer.validated_data.get('username')
            password = serializer.validated_data.get('password')
            user = authentication.authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                response = Response({'message': 'User logged in successfully'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                return response
            else:
                return Response({'message': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        else:
            # If the serializer is not valid, return validation errors
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and this request by axios in vue.js application

```
<script setup>

import axios from 'axios'
import {ref, onMounted} from 'vue'


const email = ref("");
const password = ref("");
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true



function login() {
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login/', {
        username: email.value,
        password: password.value,
    })`your text`
}
</script>
```

when i make request, cookie(session) is load to database, but it is not loaded to browser. Do you have any suggestions why?

When i make request from 127.0.0.1:8000/api/login endpoint it works as expected. It doesn't work when i make request from localhost:5173 by axios.

Answer (score 0):

In the [django restframework documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication), it's clear that SessionAuthentication should be used in relation with a standard Django login page.

> Warning: Always use Django's standard login view when creating login pages. This will ensure your login views are properly protected.

SessionAuthentication is a convenience for using django standard pages with API routes provided by restframework. If you don't plan to use django standard page in your app, it's probably better to use another authentification mecanism, like [BasicAuth](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#basicauthentication)

Comment: Was this answer helpfull ?